# Send chat.postmessage from App user account

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I've been working on an internal Slack application that integrates with our company's ticketing system.

Right now, I'm using a couple of Internal Webhooks URLs to post messages to different channels for different purposes. Those messages are delivered with the user being the app's name with "App" next to that. This is all good.

Now, I'm adding an extra functionality that would send a private message to individual users using `chat.postmessage`. I'm looking at different parameters like `as_user` and what not, but I want to know what I need to do to have these private messages come in "from" that same App user. As of now they are coming in "from" Slack API Tester. I know I can change the username and icon, but I was wondering if I could send them straight "from" them app, using a different token or something similar.

Here's a sample of some of the code I'm using right now:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
$data = http_build_query([
    //Slack Legacy API token found at 
    //https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens
    "token" => "xoxp-0000000-00000-0000-0000",
    "channel" => "@gbewley", 
    "text" => "Hello Graham", 
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

Comment: Additionally, on this page, I'm told I need a bot access token to post as a bot user. I have created a bot user on my App, but I do not know how to find the token for that bot user. 

I'm on this page: https://api.slack.com/bot-users

I clicked on the link in the documentation that says "bot user token" but that just brings me to a management page for my integrations, can't figure out where the token is.

Comment: this is new question, unrelated to the first. Please post it as new question on Slackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to send messages that originates from any user A who uses your script. Sorry, but Slack does not allow that. Your only options for originator of a message with `chat.postMessage` are:

- App name, sending with "as_user" false (this is default)
- Bot user, using the bot token
- User that installed your app (that would be you I guess), sending with "as_user" true and using the full access token

As you already mentioned a common workaround is to "fake" the user name. However, in that case Slack will still show an "App" tag indicating that the message is coming from an app.